# How to replace labels of json array and add information prior to the array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I'm fetching data from mysql like ...

```
$query = "SELECT legal_country, count(*) FROM accounts GROUP BY legal_country ORDER BY count(*) DESC";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

$data = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

return json_encode( $data );
```

Current result is:

```
[{"legal_country":"US","count(*)":"107865"},{"legal_country":"DE","count(*)":"44711"},{"legal_country":"SL","count(*)":"1"}]
```

Yet, my goal is to have the json string like:

```
{"map": "worldLow", "areas": [{"id": "US","value": "107865"},{"id": "DE","value": "44711"},{"id": "SL","value": "1"}]}
```

How can I add {"map": "worldLow", "areas": .... } prior to the array and how can I exchange the labels legal_country -> id and count(*) -> value  ??

In addition, this is a working example with 'echo' ... yet I need it with the 'return' function ...

```
$prefix = '';
echo '{"map": "worldLow", "areas": [';
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    echo $prefix . " {\n";
    echo '  "id": "' . $row['legal_country'] . '",' . "\n";
    echo '  "value": "' . $row['count(*)'] . '"' . "\n";
    echo " }";
$prefix = ",\n";
}

echo "\n]}";
```

The working example with echo looks like this:

```
{"map": "worldLow", "areas": [ {
  "id": "US",
  "value": "107865"
 },
 {
  "id": "DE",
  "value": "44711"
 },
 {
  "id": "SL",
  "value": "1"
 }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the result according to your requirement.

```
$query = "SELECT legal_country AS `id`, count(*) AS `value` 
          FROM accounts 
          GROUP BY legal_country 
          ORDER BY count(*) DESC";
$dataArr = $areasArr = array();
if ($result = mysql_query( $query )) {
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        $areasArr[] = $row;
    }
    $dataArr = array(
        "map"   => "worldLow",
        "areas" => $areasArr
    );
}
return json_encode( $dataArr, true );
```

Also use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: Unfortunately this is returning 'null'

Comment: Are you tried with `return json_encode( $dataArr, true );`. variable name was different when i posted

Comment: Fantastic ... now it's working. The data is in the table!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change slightly your query and `$data` before using `json_encode`

```
 $query = "SELECT legal_country as `id`, count(*) as `value` FROM accounts GROUP BY legal_country ORDER BY count(*) DESC";
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    $json= array();
    $area = array();
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
            $area[] = $row;
        }
    $data = array(
        'map' => 'worldlow',
        'area' => $area,
      );
    return json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: This is creating the json as hoped, thanks. Yet, the chart (amCharts) is still not loading the array. I added the working example with 'echo' above ... but I need it with 'return' (due to the MVC I'm using). Might it be due to the fact that the working example has "\n" in it?

Comment: Might this be an amCharts issue? @PhilippM can you post more code of the problem?

Comment: Likely. Did you see the edit I provided above? That's the working sample from (at the very bottom of the page in the zip) https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/ .... The only difference I see are the empty spaces right after the labels "\n" ... is it possible to include them in the sample you provided? (if that is the issue)

Comment: @PhilippM can you provide the new and modified json output ?

Comment: But this echo example is rendering the data into the map. Unfortunately with the echo example the TYPO3 extension I want to embed it adds 'null' to the array. Please see below your sample the current result of your samle. At the very top I provided the echo working example from amCharts ...

Comment: i think your json is as you want it in the `echo example` if you want to feed data to amCharts from the new json then you simply have to pass the `area` part of the json to amCharts,